# Error (noSuchName) from netsnmp api, but snmpget works just fine

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I have a program that is using the netsnmp C API to query device for snmp information. So far everything has been working fine, but when I polled a new OID (1.3.6.1.2.1.138.1.1.1.3.0 (isisSysID)) its doesn't work, and I just get the noSuchName error, other OIDs such as from the IF-MIB have been working fine.

However when I test using snmpget from the same system to the same endpoint it works fine. (v1 or v2c)
snmpget -v2c -c   1.3.6.1.2.1.138.1.1.1.3.0

Thanks.

Comment: Use a tool like Wireshark to analyze the actual SNMP packets sent to the wire and you should observe the differences easily to get you started.

Comment: ah, that would make sense, for some reason I had just assumed that my code wasn't even sending anything out. Thanks.

Comment: So found part of the issue, it is sending the request with a zeroed out OID that is completely buggered.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue,
In my code I was using the method get_node to convert a OID string to the OID object used for the request by the netsnmp api. This works fine if the OID you are using contains a text named portion such as "sysName.0" but fails if the OID you use is entirely numerical ie "1.3.6.1.2.1.138.1.1.1.3.0".

Luckily a workaround is that you can shorten that OID to "mib-2.138.1.1.1.3.0" as "mib-2" is the text replacement for "1.3.6.1.2.1"

Comment: Yeah `get_node` is part of the MIB utility functions, not designed to do what you're using it for. Didn't you want [`read_objid`](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/dev/agent/group__mib__utilities.html#ga1e4e5be57e55313a6c2bd2aabc065966)?